# Convert an entire row to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I have this CSV table of Bonds (actually it's a large data but I captured only a few). I named the dataframe as test.

[image: CSV table]

The top row is the Bonds Name, the furthest left column is the Date, and the index 0 row is the Maturity Date. I want to convert all Date and all Maturity Date to datetime type.

As expected, if I typed this code

```
test[['Date']] = test[['Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
print(test)
```

This successfully converted only the Date column to datetime but not the Maturity Date.

How can I convert both to datetime? Because later I want to subtract the Maturity Date and Date to get the Bonds Age.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the first row with `iloc` to convert it to datetime type

```py
test.iloc[0] = pd.to_datetime(test.iloc[0])
test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Date'])
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked, but what should i add to make it only return the year, month, and date (without time)? @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @Jannjann You can use `pd.to_datetime(test.iloc[0]).dt.date`

Comment: thank you very much! youre so helpful^^ have a great day ahead @Ynjxsjmh